# How to use function() in JQuery.first() such as in each()

Tags: jquery

I wonder why it doesn't work to wrap a function() in JQuery.first() like in Jquery.each()?

While this works fine:

`$(this).each( function() { something });`

This does not work:

`$(this).first( function() { something });`

Do I really have to use this workaround (?) :

`$(this).first().each( function() { something });`

EDIT:

Sometimes stupid questions come. We all know this especially when we're deep in the development and forget to think simple. Thanks for waking me up... :-)

```
function( $(element).first() );
```

it is obviously the right approach

Comment: Why? Because as the [`.first()` docs](https://api.jquery.com/first/) state, _"This method does not accept any arguments."_

Comment: `.each` and `.first` are *drastically* different in what they do. Why should they accept the same arguments? If you need to do something with the first element, you'd probably need to use `fn(jqElement.first())` or `fn(jqElement[0])`. Since you're wrapping `this` I don't even know why you'd need to use either `first` or `each` - you *always* have a single element. Assuming `this` is a DOM node.

Comment: I upvoted to counteract the downvote. Why downvote someone trying to understand a coding issue.

Comment: Probably I wasn't precise of what I want to achieve. There are moments when I am so "in" the JQuery to forget to leave it for a while and apply JS logic instead of keep trying to use JQuery for everything. In this case I did not ask right - fair enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Edited in response to comments.)

If you have a $(this) then it is almost certainly already a single element. You can just go ahead and use it:

```
$(this).addClass("special");
```

If you have a set of elements, but only want to do something to the first matching element, then first() gets you the actual element:

```
ele = $(".my_matches").first();
```

Then you can just do whatever you want to do with the element, for example:

```
if (ele.hasClass("special")){
   ele.addClass("super");
}
```

or pass it to a function:

```
do_stuff(ele);
```

If you want to use each(), but only do something to the first element, you can use a break. However, that would be silly.

Comment: `$(this).first();` will *most likely* just put a single element in a jQuery wrapper, so the `.first()` call is not needed - there is nothing to filter here. When calling `jqElement.each((i, el) => {})` the raw elements are passed as `el`, thus `$(this).first().each(fn)` (or `$(this).each(fn)`) would be equivalent to calling `fn(0, this)`.

Comment: It's the most likely scenario. To have it be anything different, it will have to manually be set to either a selector or a collection of elements. I'd go on a limb and say that I don't expect OP to be doing that.

Comment: Edited my response to account for that. Not sure if OP meant to use a single element or a matching set.

Comment: The question is very unclear to me. I don't know what the intent is, it seems like [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).